# Getting a struct timeval for a few seconds into the future

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that returns  a time stamp for a few seconds into the future.

Currently my attempt has been

```
struct timeval time;
gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
time.tv_usec += 10; // 10 seconds into the future
```

I will then later get a gettimeofday and do a comparison

And then do the comparison with the macro on [this other stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858075/3833632) post.

To figure out when I can do the 10 seconds later code.

Is this correct? I dont fully understand the mechanics of struct timeval and like if there would be edge cases if I for example tried to increment by a sub 1 amount of seconds or perhaps an above hour amount of seconds.

Comment: Please review std::promise and std::future.  And perhaps the tutorial   at "https://thispointer.com/c11-multithreading-part-8-stdfuture-stdpromise-and-returning-values-from-thread/".  There are many tutorials that seem related.

Comment: `tv_usec` holds microseconds, not seconds.